# Use different aggregation strategy in camel depending on some header

Tags: java, apache-camel

What is the correct way to use different aggregation strategy in camel depending on some header? Is the following way fine or is there any other cleaner approach to do this?

```
from("direct:start") 
     .choice() 
     .when(header("foo").equalTo("bar")) 
            .aggregate(header("id"), new BodyInAggregatingStrategy()).completionTimeout(3000).endChoice() 
     .when(header("foo").equalTo("foobar")) 
            .aggregate(header("id"), new BodyOutAggregatingStrategy()).completionTimeout(3000) 
     .to("mock:aggregated");
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need implement your own compound aggregation strategy, and then aggregate accordingly to the header value, eg from Camel pov there is 1 strategy and it calls the aggregate method. Then you figure out what to do depending on the header value. You can just delegate to another aggregation strategy on its behalf.

Then you do not need the Content Based Router.